# LEDs are not glowing with the same intensity in a LED matrix

Tags: led-matrix, 74hc595

In my 16*8 LED matrix, I am switching the rows, so the duty cycle is 100/8 = 12.5%. Now, when the row contains fewer LEDs to be lit, they all glow brightly, but when more LEDs are turned on, they are all dimmer, ike in this photo, where the fifth row is lighting up dimly:

[image]

I know that more LEDs means more current, so my current is not sufficient and I tried the following:

Initially, I was using 3-off 74HC595 IC and power input from a 5 V Arduino output.

Then I tried to light each LED independently. It solved the intensity problem, but it reduced the duty cycle to 100/128 = 0.78% and it gave a flickering effect.

Then I thought that the Arduino was not able to provide sufficient current to light the 16 LEDs in a whole row. I changed the power source to 1 A output 5 V mobile charger but the problem persisted.

According to me, the 74HC595 is not able to provide sufficient current.

Please give me the remedy. Also, when I saw this project in a video, it did not have this problem. Some were using a 74HC595 and other were using a MAX7219.

Comment: Please post a schematic diagram of your circuit.  There are many ways of designing such a circuit, and it would help immensely if we could see which way you have chosen.

Comment: Ok, give me some time, I am new to it.

Comment: Your row driver is weak : it can supply current for 4 LEDs but not for 11. If you're driving 1 row at a time, each column driver drives 1 LED at a time so the current limit R should be in the column, and the row driver rated to drive 16 LEDs without increasing voltage drop. Need schematic to say more.

Comment: Looks to me that top, middle, and bottom row are different brightness than the other rows.

Comment: Do you by chance have a single resistor limiting current for multiple LEDs turned on at any given time?

Comment: @Tom Carpenter, yes I have used single resistor for multiple leds

Comment: @YashMittal That single resistor is your problem then.

Answer (score 1):

74HC595 is a poor chip choice, able to source just 70mA total for all outputs before being overstressed.
You will see more consistent results with a proper hardware setup: Two MAX7219s, one for each display, outputs multipexed at 800 Hz, simple register write to update a column or row;  or if you insist on implementing your own multiplexing, then MIC5891 for current source to the anodes and TPIC6B595 for current sink on the cathodes.